# How to get the height of a div and apply it to another on load and resize using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I basicly have a collection of divs structured like this:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to get the height of `items` then divide it by 6 and apply it to every `item`.

I can do this with jQuery doing something like and then wrapping it inside onLoad & onResize events.

```
$itemsHeight = $('.items').height();
$itemHeight = $itemsHeight/6;
$(.item).css('height' : $itemHeight);
```

However angular is confusing me and I can't seem to figure out how to A) get the elements height and B) how to have it update on resize and on load.

**UPDATE:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="items" resizeContainer>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('AngularApp')
  .directive('resizeContainer', function ($window) {
    var linkFn;
    linkFn = function(scope,element,attrs) {
      function setHeight() {       
        var winHeight = $(window).height(); // Get window height
        var headerHeight = $('.header').height(); // Get height of the header

        console.log(winHeight, headerHeight); //Display heights to make sure their working

        elem.css('height', winHeight - topRecipeHeight + 'px');  // take away header height from the window height to work out the height of the container.
      }

      setHeight(); // Fire setHeight function

      var windowListenerDeregistraion = $(window).on('resize', setHeight); // Fire setHeight function on window resize

      scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
          windowListenerDeregistraion();
      });
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: linkFn
    }
});
```

My problem is now that this still is not working, I feel I am close to getting the height of the container but I can't even get the `console.log` to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Is is quite simple thing, first get the height of parent dive using below expression

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#PARENT_DIV_ID'))[0].offsetHeight
```

OR if you are free to use javascript than use document.getElementById instead of document.querySelector.

Divide above height with length of childs and than Set height of child div through a directive in a manner shown below :

```
    angular.module('myApp', []).directive('child_div', function() {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.height(attrs.new_height);
    }
});
```

in above directive you have seen that there is a 'new_height' attribute is checked in  every 'child_div'. So at the time of creation of child div pass directive 'child_div' and an attr new_height you got from above calculation.

If you have any confusion regarding directive see this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bk-CC61zMZk.

I have recommend to use directive as all the DOM manuplation are done in directives only.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you will always have 6 items, why not solve this using pure css?

http://jsfiddle.net/fU2eY/

Basically just set each item height to 100/6, or `height: 16.667%`

---

If your item set is dynamic, then you will have to create a custom directive, and apply it to the `items` div. Eg: `<div class="items" custom-child-height="">`

Then your directive should:

- Get the height of the items div
- Count the number of children
- Go through each child and set the height via css accordingly
- Bind to the resize event and update also
- Don't forget to run on load using `$timeout` so that the calculations occur after the items have been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set number of elements every time, then you can use simple CSS percentages for the height of each child element.

If the number of child elements is dynamic, you might do something like this:

```
<!-- HTML -->

<items>
    <item ng-repeat="item in items"></item>
</items>
```

```
// inside your controller

$scope.items = [ /* your items */ ];
```

```
// directive

.directive('item',[function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            function setHeight() {
                elm.css('height',+elm.parent('items').outerHeight()/scope.items.length);
            }

            setHeight();

            var windowListenerDeregistraion = $(window).on('resize', setHeight);

            scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
                windowListenerDeregistraion();
            });
        }
    };
]});
```

This solution, however, couples your directive with your `items` model in your code (if you have such a model).

Comment: I decided I actually needed a cross between the CSS method and the Angular method. I am able to use CSS to resize the child items but the actual container item needs to be sized using angular. I have updated the original post with the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using pure CSS. 
see a working [Plunker](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/K4Yr2bJfitvKY3I6qiFr/).

To use this technique, you need to have fixed height for non-content elements like header, sidebars and footer. 
You use CSS [Absolute Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) combined with CSS [Top](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp) and [Bottom](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp).

Check the plunk and if you need more clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

first thing I noticed is that you're changing the css of 'elem' but in the function you defined it as 'element' so try changing 'elem' to 'element'. I'm almost sure that this is your problem, 'cause I see nothing else wrong with the code!